# correctly reference jquery mobile locally

Tags: jquery-mobile

user3568918 has responded to the following question:

[jQuery Mobile not working with Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371919/jquery-mobile-not-working-with-internet-explorer#)

**Dont forget to keep the right binding Order:**

- jquery mobile css
- jquery script
- jquery mobile script

**My question is :**

When I go to download page of jquery mobile 
https:/ /jquerymobile.com/download/
I see two viable options for me :

1. Download the javascript, css and images :

https:/ /jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.zip

2. Download the minified javascript :

http:/ /code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

If I choose 1, two additional subfolders "demos" and "images" are created, which have their own sub-folders. 
**Do I have to reference all these subfolders in my html ?**

If I choose 2, which is to download the minified javascript only, **how do I reference the images that I want to use for icons?**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: assuming your `index.html` is the root, you should reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.1.4.5.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Then, the directory structure on your server shall be like this:

```
\index.html

-- All jQuery files shall be in \js subfolder and \css subfolder

\js\
----jquery-1.11.2.min.js
----jquery-1.11.2.min.map
----jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
----jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.map
(...other stuff)

\css\
-----jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
-----jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.min.css
-----jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css
-----jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.min.css
-----jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.min.css
(...other stuff)

\css\images\
------------ajax-loader.gif
------------icons-18-black.png
------------icons-18-white.png
(...other stuff)

\css\images\icons-png\
----------------------action-black.png
----------------------action-white.png
(...a lot of other stuff)

\css\images\icons-svg\
----------------------action-black.svg
----------------------action-white.svg
(...a lot of other stuff)
```

**EDIT:**

subfolders `demos` and `images` inside the zip file are ready for you if you need to have the JQM demos also available on your local site, there is also a custom css file special for the demos.

I think this will also clarify some aspect of your question: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I should therefore download the javascript, css and images : 
https:/ /jquerymobile.com/resources/download/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.zip , shouldn't I?

Comment: @user3567338: on older browsers that don't support svg the framework falls back to png icons. Here are two other references for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709337/jquery-mobile-1-4-icon-images and https://forum.jquery.com/topic/newbie-jquery-mobile-1-4-icons. Feel free to ask again if somewhat is not clear enough, keep in mind this information may subject to change with JQM versions.

Comment: @user3567338: please see my edit about images embedded in CSS, maybe this will solve some your doubts - you may not need icons in subfolders, if you are satisfied with the standard JQM icons.

Comment: Well, I gave it a try but the local reference is not working. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  DOES NOT WORK. 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Notice the local jquery reference differs from web reference.

Comment: Folders

\js\
jquery-3.1.1.min.js
jquery-3.1.1.min.map
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.map

Comment: \css\   < file extensions removed >
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.
jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.
jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.min.

Comment: \css\images\
ajax-loader.gif

\css\images\icons-png\
all the png files

\css\images\icons-svg\
all the svg files

Comment: @netdev2000: what jQuery version you are using? please note: JQM Version 1.4.5 is compatible with jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1 (see JQM [home page](https://jquerymobile.com/)) Please tell me also which IE version do you experience trouble..

Comment: I am using jquery-3.1.1 in IE11 : <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> . I will give it a try with 2.1 if I can get one, at the moment I can get only jquery-2.2.4.min.js from the CDN. If I get the full version number then I can download. W3Schools mentioned jquery-1.11.3.min.js in their example. So I may as well download that version and try.

Comment: You are right. **The correct version did the trick.** I downloaded  jquery-1.11.3.min.js and the **basic page with header, body and footer** is working exactly as it is supposed to be in IE11. Here is the code in the head section : **<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>**